# HashTable in java own size

Tags: java, size, hashtable

I want to create a hashtable which is a specific size each time. I want it to be 10 x the number of blocks (using substring()) stored in "list".

```
for (int k = 0; k < foo.length() - blockSize + 1; k++) {
            list = foo.substring(k, k + blockSize);
            System.out.println(list);
}
```

I have looked online and can't find any solution for this. Can I get some clarification on this?

Thanks

Comment: Try: *Map<K,V> map = HashMap<K,V>(yourNumber * 10);*

Comment: Or Java 7: Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>(yourNumber * 10);

Comment: Please note [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) doesn't allow `null` keys or values, whereas [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does.

Answer (score 1):

[HashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#Hashtable%28int,%20float%29) (are you sure you don't want a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead?) has a constructor overload that takes a loadfactor.

```
public Hashtable(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)
```

> Constructs a new, empty hashtable with the specified initial capacity and the specified load factor.
>
> Parameters:
>   `initialCapacity` - the initial capacity of the hashtable.
>   `loadFactor` - the load factor of the hashtable.

[The documentation on a loadfactor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. The initial capacity and load factor parameters are merely hints to the implementation. The exact details as to when and whether the rehash method is invoked are implementation-dependent.

What you should take away from this is that you have no power over how much space is allocated by the `HashTable`. All you can do is signify a treshold when the new allocation should happen. How much this should be is not within your power (although you can look at the source code to see how the new space is determined and adjust your code based on that).

Comment: Can you expand on this? What is a "loadFactor"?

Comment: @user3364788: added expansion.